# How to make SVG respect a text-width and have it break lines accordingly?

Tags: svg, text-formatting

Like in HTML, but I'd prefer to not use foreignObject.

This should be a standard-problem so I guess there is a standard-solution, couldn't find one though.

Thanks

Raffael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rendered the line breaking aided by the PHP-function imagettfbbox(), to measure the line-length.

Best

Raffael

Comment: That seems really fragile, given that the SVG may render using different font size, family, or layout that what PHP is measuring.

Comment: Not in my case, as we convert the SVG into PNG using RSVG

Answer (score 2):

The SVG 1.2T [`<textArea>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#TextInAnArea) is the standard way. It's possible to implement similar functionality using javascript too, which can be good as a fallback. See e.g http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/textFlow/.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... the label for that is "word wrap" and it seems like this is only implemented in SVG 1.2. Though the example on W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#TextInAnArea) is not supported by FireFox ... oh my

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is SVG1.2, but it's unimplemented so I guess the foreignObject solution is the best at the moment.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying it's unimplemented. Opera supports it fwiw.